# Pagination issue in laravel when specifying a connection

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

The issue is it doesn't work.

To clarify, if I perform the following:

```
$invoices = DB::connection(MY_CONNECTION)->table('invoice')->get();
```

And then pass it to a blade view, I can output it like this:

```
var pzFieldArray = {{ json_encode($invoices) }}
```

This will produce an array of data in javascript. This tells me that the connection works fine.

However, if I perform the following:

```
$invoices = DB::connection(MY_CONNECTION)->table('invoice')->paginate(10);
```

And pass that to the same view, then I get an empty javascript array.

My question is simple: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this with `paginate()`, it returns an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`:

```
json_encode($invoices->toArray());
enter code here
```

Also, you may only pass the data array like:

```
json_encode($invoices->toArray()['data']);
```

Or this:

```
$invoices = $invoices->toArray();
json_encode($invoices['data']);
```

So, only data (records) will be `encoded` but other properties won't be available in the `json`, in this case you may need all properties such as `tota`, `per_page` etc. An example of `json` encode data:

```
$user = User::paginate(5);
json_encode($user->toArray());
```

Output:

> string
>   '{"total":10,"per_page":5,"current_page":1,"last_page":2,"from":1,"to":5,"data":[{"id":1,"first_name":"Sheikh","last_name":"Heera","username":"heera","email":"heerasheikh@ymail.com","role_id":1,"bio":"Lorem
>   ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
>   veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
>   ea commodo
>   consequat.","profile_picture":"http://blog.dev/images/user_1/profile_image/heera_new'...
>   (length=2618)

**Update:** Well, it could be done using `toJson()` directly as well (I missed it):

```
return Invoices::paginate(10)->toJson();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It turns out that there is an easier way, and I have added an answer explaining that. I've +1ed your answer though because it also works.

Answer (score 1):

Sheikh Heera was correct in that paginate itself wouldn't do the task. However, there is an easier way. All I need to do is add the following to the paginate line:

```
->toJson();
```

The full line will now read:

```
$invoices = DB::connection(MY_CONNECTION)->table('invoice')->paginate(10)->toJson();
```

And you can convert it to javascript simply:

```
return Response::json($invoices);
```

This works when you are doing Ajax calls, but if you want to include it in a view, its just a simple:

```
<script>
var pzFieldArray = {{ $invoices }}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow! You did it better, +1 and also updated my answer as well for future reference :-)